# Get latest child record - EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

The table `Users` has a few relationships on another table

So here is the snippet code

```
var users = DbContext.Users
           .Include(x => x.ApplicationUserGroups)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ApplicationGroup)
           .Include(x => x.FormSubmit)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.FormLevel)
           .Where(x => true);
```

So now, I need the latest record from `FormSubmit`. So I modified the query somewhat like this:

```
var users = DbContext.Users
           .Include(x => x.ApplicationUserGroups)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ApplicationGroup)
           .Include(x => x.FormSubmit.OrderByDescending(i => i.CreationDate).Take(1))
                .ThenInclude(x => x.FormLevel)
           .Where(x => true);
```

But I got the exception:

`"Message": "The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from FormSubmit i in x.FormSubmit orderby [i].CreationDate desc select [i] => Take(1)}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393."`

Any idea how to get latest record from `FormSubmit`?

Comment: Add your `Users`, `ApplicationUserGroups`, `FormSubmit` etc models into question.

Comment: EF core was not supported filtered or ordered include, in your case, have to filter the latest record from FormSubmit afterwards. You can refer to "https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far you cannot achieve it directly because neither eager or lazy loading in EF Core supports ordering or filtering in child collection.

As your requirement is not clear I am providing possible alternative solution for all possible cases:

**1) If you want latest `FormSubmit` of a certain user:**

```
var users = DbContext.Users
           .Include(x => x.ApplicationUserGroups)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ApplicationGroup)
           .Include(x => x.FormSubmit)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.FormLevel)
           .Where(x => true && x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

var latestFormSubmit = users.Select(u => u.FormSubmit).OrderByDescending(fs => fs.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

**2) If you want latest `FormSubmit` among all users:**

```
var users = DbContext.Users
           .Include(x => x.ApplicationUserGroups)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ApplicationGroup)
           .Include(x => x.FormSubmit)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.FormLevel)
           .Where(x => true).ToList();

var latestFormSubmit = users.SelectMany(u => u.FormSubmit).OrderByDescending(fs => fs.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault();

    //Or

var latestFormSubmit = DbContext.FormSubmits.Include(x => x.FormLevel).OrderByDescending(fs => fs.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: You can omit `.Include(x => x.ApplicationUserGroups).ThenInclude(x => x.ApplicationGroup)` from the query if you need only latest `FormSubmit`.

Comment: I would be careful using this example. You are loading the ENTIRE table of Users into memory before filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation properties (like your `User.FormSubmit` property) are designed to hold *all* the related entities (or nothing, if they're not loaded).

You simply can't use `Include()` like that. `Include()` is only used for retrieving *all* the related records.

If you just want a single related record, you need to do that separately. For example:

```
var users = DbContext.Users
           .Include(x => x.ApplicationUserGroups)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ApplicationGroup)
           .Where(x => true);

foreach (var user in users) {
    var latest = DbContext.FormSubmits.Include(s => s.FormLevel).Where(s => s.UserId == user.UserId).OrderByDescending(i => i.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault()
    //Do other stuff...
}
```

Doing it this way will *only* retrieve the latest post for each user. If you do `.Include(x => x.FormSubmit).ThenInclude(x => x.FormLevel)` in your first query and then filter, it will end up getting *all* the submissions for each user, which is more data than you are going to actually use.